# pausing for loop after every iteration and display the results MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, pause

I have the following code where I call a function in a loop and pause it after every iteration:

```
[num,txt1,~]=xlsread('test.xlsx',1);
for i=2:5
    [num,txt2,~]=xlsread('test.xlsx',i);
    for j=1:3
        txt_input=txt2(2:end,j);
        neurPep=neuroPred(txt1,txt_input);
       pause
    end
   pause
end
```

I expected the Workspace would show up the values of the computed variables everytime I pause the loop, but only the values corresponding to the very last iteration are being shown towards the end.

What changes do I need to make such that values are updated after every loop and shown in the Workspace?

Comment: I would replace `pause` with `keyboard`.  `keyboard` takes you to the debugger interface so all your values should be there.  To continue, type `dbcont` in the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pause` command only suspends Matlab execution.  Since the normal flow of Matlab execution is not to update the workspace, pausing doesn't do what you want in this instance.  The `keyboard` command takes Matlab into debug mode.  This mode will update the workspace with your current values.  You can continue execution by typing `dbcont` into the command line.

Another option is to open the .m file in the Editor and click on the "-" next to the line number on the left of the line.  This will also enter debug mode.  In that case hit F5, type `dbcont` or press the play button to continue execution.

The takeaway here is: Debug mode is your friend.

Here are the references:  [pause](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html)  [keyboard](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/keyboard.html)